# Using a c++ static library (CCFits) in Xcode iOS Project

Tags: c++, iphone, ios, c, xcode

I am trying to using the CCfits library in an iOS project. CCfits is a C++ wrapper to the c library cfitsio.
I have the source code to both of these, and also have them built as static libraries (.a files). I would like to add the CCfits library (libCCfits.a) to an iOS project but when I am confused on how to access the library classes from my iPhone source files. I have the library added under "Link Binary with Libraries".
I understand that Xcode needs me to import a header file, but what is the proper way to attach the headers to the project? Do I need to make a framework file somehow? Or is the .a file enough?

Comment: c library : http://heasarc.gsfc.nasa.gov/fitsio/
c++ wrapper library : http://heasarc.gsfc.nasa.gov/fitsio/CCfits/
I am essentially trying to make an obj-c wrapper to the c++ library.

Answer (score 0):

You can easily mix C++ and Objective-C using Objective-C++. In XCode just rename your .m files to .mm and it will recognize the files as Objective-C++. Then you can use the C++ classes in your Objective-C code ([some restrictions apply](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Objective-C#Objective-C.2B.2B), but not many).

Since Objective-C is an extension to C you can use C libraries in any Objective-C program easily.

See https://stackoverflow.com/posts/10156243/edit

Comment: Is Objective-C++ well-supported going forward? I don't see much indication in the Apple docs that it is.